Cypress - How to get rid of Chrome 'Change your password' popup
In Cypress the following message keeps popping up in Chrome:

Other than changing the password, how can I get rid of the popup or stop it appearing?
I have tried setting 'credentials_enable_service' and 'profile.password_manager_enabled' to false in cypress.config.js but that had no effect.
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
    if (browser.family === 'chromium' && browser.name !== 'electron') {
      
      // Disable Chrome's "Save password?" pop up
      launchOptions.preferences.default.credentials_enable_service = false
      launchOptions.preferences.default.profile.password_manager_enabled = false
      
      launchOptions.args.push('--disable-ios-password-suggestions','--credentials_enable_service=false', '--profile.password_manager_enabled=false')

      return launchOptions
    }

I have also tried these:
cy.on('window:alert', (buttonText) => {
  return false; //clicks on cancel 
});
or with confirmation dialog:

cy.on('window:confirm', (buttonText) => {
  return false;
});

But I can't get the message to disappear
